# Run the code only once in php

Tags: php

I need to run the program only once; afterwards it will run another program. How is it possible?

```
if()
{
include 'first.php';
}
else
{
include 'second.php';
}
```

I don't want to put conditions in the if condition.

Please can anyone help?

Comment: Have you had a look at require_once or include_once?

Comment: You need to give more information. In what context are you trying to run the code in 'first.php'?

Comment: what i am saying is first.php run only once after second.php run simultaneously i don't want suggestion in include_once & require_once

Comment: i am writing the jquery program in which it has two php file ie first and second file i need to run the first php file only once and second run continuouly

Comment: is anyone of the script executes for any specific condition?

Comment: Could you give an example or something? I really don't know what you mean.

Comment: "second script run continously"-- what is the count you want to run it.. iterrate it in for loop

Comment: second script runs when i scroll down to the bottom of the window

Comment: you can use session.when a user visit to your site set a new session:`if(!isset($_SESSION['x'])) include 'first.php';`

Comment: "second script runs when i scroll down to the bottom of the window" do you mean you scrolling the page down??? thats the event you want the second script to execute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store in $_SESSION a flag that marks your first.php has ran once, like this:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['first_run'])){
    $_SESSION['first_run'] = 1;
    include 'first.php';
}

include 'second.php';
```

Answer (score 1):

Use lock files.

```
$lockfile = '/some/writable/path/executed.lock';
if (file_exists($lockfile)) {
    include('second.php');
} else {
    file_put_contents($lockfile, '');
    include('first.php');
}
```

Comment: can you plz ellaborate lock file, is it default php file or anything else

Comment: lock file will be uinque for all user (unless you generate one for each user.. but at that point there are sessions).

Comment: A lock file is just an empty file. You create it when something happens, then you can check if it's there to know if that something has happened. The technique is used extensively in UNIX systems and dates back to the days when using simple techniques like this without a lot of wrapper code was common.

Comment: Depends on your use case. You want to run the script once and only once? Use a lock file. Want to run it once every time a user visits? Use session. It will expire after half an hour or so first.php will run again when the user comes back. Want to run it once per user, as long as he doesn't delete cookies? Use a cookie that doesn't expire. Want to track the user at any cost? Use flash LocalStorage.

Comment: Gee, who the heck downvoted this, and why? Nothing wrong with guessing what is meant on an ambiguous question, can be edited later.

Answer (score 1):

just sign with session

```
if(isset($_SESSION['done'])){    
    $_SESSION['done'] = 'done';    
    include('first.php'); 
}else{    
    include('second.php'); 
}
```

Comment: You have to negate the first line. `if(!isset)`

Answer (score 0):

Let PHP handle that for you with `require_once` and/or `include_once`

Inside `first.php`:

```
your 
.
.
.
code 
.
.
.
here

define('FIRST_RUN', false);
```

In your script:

```
define('FIRST_RUN', true);
include_once 'first.php';

if( !FIRST_RUN )
    include 'second.php'
```

Answer (score -2):

What did you try???

```
if(!file_exists('/tmp/foo')) { 
    touch('/tmp/foo');
    include 'first.php'; 
} else { 
    include 'second.php'; 
}
```