# create variable only once in php

Tags: php, session, isset, require-once

I have been looking for a way to run one piece of code only once in php. I want to create and set a variable at the beginning of the webpage and whenever I call that file, the code will ignore that line.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682229/run-the-code-only-once-in-php) in which there are basically two suggestions: `setting a session variable` and `creating a lock file` which I don't want to since there might be many users at the same time and I need to have a lock file for each one of them.

I tried the first option but it doesn't work.

Here are my two files:

**config.php**

```
<?php 
     if (at the beginning){
         $variable = something
         echo 'hello';
     }
     else
          do something
?>
```

**second.php**

```
<?php
     require_once 'config.php'    
     //do some other stuff
?>
```

Whenever second.php is called, it prints 'hello' in the webpage, so `if (at the beginning)` returns `true` even though it is not at the beginning. Note that, I check whether at the beginning by `if(!isset($_SESSION['done'])){ $_SESSION['done'] = 'done'; }`

I wonder what is my mistake and how can I solve the problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: do you want it to run once per request, once per session, once per year?

Comment: @RolandStarke: Whenever the webpage is requested, i.e. for each user opening the webpage.

Comment: So the missing negation was just a typo? Please comment if you make changes that affect program's behaviour.

Comment: @syck: Yes, I directly copy and pasted from `http://stackoverflow.com/a/9682456/2021883`, s/he made a mistake, I warned him/her as well. But it was already negated in my code.

Comment: @smttsp if you only include the file with `require_once` than it should not be executed multiple times per request

Comment: @RolandStarke: With this code, for each user I will create new session right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program flow for config.php should be:

```
<?php 
     session_start();

     if (!isset($_SESSION['done'])) {
         $_SESSION['done'] = 1;
         echo 'hello';
     }
     else {
         // do something
     }
?>
```

Comment: Will the `session_start()` initiate the session only once or whenever the file is called? I will call `config.php` from multiple other files.

Comment: @RolandStarke: yes, I always `require_once`. Thanks a lot, it works now

Comment: `session_start()` should be called once per request. But since you use `require_once()`, config.php should not be executed more than a single time.

Comment: I don't know why but it executes multiple times. `if (!isset(....) echo 'first'); else{echo 'again???';}`. The first time it prints `first`, then it always prints `again???`. Also, I'm sure I'm always calling with `require_once`.

Comment: Within a single script run? You can use [debug-backtrace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) from inside config.php to find out which function originate the require statements from.